# persistence.xml cache property warning

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm using eclipse indigo for EE developement to develop an SE project, just to take benefit from the JPA project support.
I created a JPA project, here's the properties of my persistence.xml file:

```
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.reference-mode" value="WEAK" />
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.size.default" value="5000"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
            value="jdbc:derby:DB;create=true;" />

        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="both" />
    </properties>
```

a warning appears :

```
"eclipselink.cache.shared.default" is a legacy entity caching property. Consider migration to JPA 2.0 and EclipseLink cache settings via annotation or XMLmapping file
```

I'm using the last release of eclipseLink (2.3.0), and [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_EclipseLink_JPA_Extensions_%28ELUG%29#How_to_Use_the_Persistence_Unit_Properties_for_Caching)'s a link to EL documentation, where there's an example for setting the property onto the persistence.xml file.
Does anybody knows the reason of the warning?

Note that i used the same property in a normal java project, and there were no warnings, it appeared only when used the JPA project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just wants to inform about use of EclipseLink Entity caching. Instead it suggests that you could use cache which is part of JPA 2.0. Usage is described among other sources here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Caching

And why it does so, is probably best explained in the request to add such a message: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=294077

Comment: Thanks for the links @MikkoM. If i'm not missing something i think the solution is to set the <shared-cache-mode> element to NONE under the persistence-unit element, (the property "eclipselink.cache.shared.default" is for use with JPA 1.0). However applying this solution led to another warning under "eclipselink.cache.size.default" ==> does-this mean that the 'cache.size' property (same for '@Cache' and '@Cacheable' annotations) concern the 2nd level cache (not the 1st level)?

Comment: Depends what is your goal. You are supposed to get warning for all such a properties that configure something that is overlapping
 with the configuration of shared cache that is part of JPA 2. It kind of suggest you to remove these settings.

<shared-cache-mode> is standard JPA 2 configuration, and setting it to NONE disables caching. This can of course seriously hit performance.

eclipselink.cache.size.default concerns shared cache (~2nd level cache)

Comment: I'm actually developing a standalone Swing application which will use a unique extended persistence-context (EntityManager). My application won't need the shared cache since there won't be any concurency (no other persistence-contexts at all), i'll need only the L1 cache related to my unique EM, and using the persistence-context WEAK mode will alleviate any memory management issues. I've removed the 'cache.size' property, but still wondering if i can use the '@Cache' and the '@Cacheable' annotations to tune L1 cache?

Comment: Both of them are only for 2nd level cache.

Comment: Well that's disapointing ... but any way thank you very much for the answers. i'll mark the answer accepted.

Comment: Unfortunately so. Only way to affect cache hold by EntityManager is to call clear when you do not have any pending changes that should be persisted and when you don't mind entities coming detached.